# Convert Wireshark Filter Expression to BPF

Tags: c#, networking, wireshark, sniffing

So I am trying to make a program that parses certain udp packets on my network. To do this I use Sharppcap and C#. I have this filter expression and it works flawlessly in wireshark: `udp and frame.protocols==eth:ethertype:ip:udp:data`.

However, when I try to implement this in my C# Application I get an Exception because the filter Expression is not BPF-Valid (I think).

Does anyone have an idea what the correct syntax would achieve the same thing in BPF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are mixing Capture Filters and Display Filters. The `udp` part of your filter seems to be a Capture Filter, while the rest is a Display Filter. The display filter just hides some results in Wireshark, while the Capture Filter, actually cuts away packages that do not match the filter. Refer to the pcap filter documentation on how to construct a filter: https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/pcap-filter.7.html

So your pcap filter in your case is essentially `udp`, you are interested in UDP packages only.

The Display Filter part is up to you to do in your code when you inspect the packages.

Comment: I understand now what you mean thanks. Do you happen to know how wireshark detects the above packet? When I inspect the packets manuually i do not seem to be able to find clear differences between pure udp data and lets say STUN packets.

Comment: Wireshark is a very powerful tool and lets you filter for values inside of the actual package too. While pcap (package capture) does its work on the transport layer. Wireshark knows a lot of different protocols that can occur as part of UDP, including STUN packages which are defined in RFC5389. Is there anything specific you want to filter?

Comment: Yes, I would only like to work with the "udp and frame.protocols==eth:ethertype:ip:udp:data"-type packets. I have found that if I exclude icmp, icmpv6, STUN and dlts I am able to get the same result as the 1st query if that helps.